# Passing a class which holds Dynamic Memory : Methods and their Efficiencies

Tags: c++, memory-management, rule-of-three

I have a class that holds some big amount of data, called `HeavyData`. This class Follows the rule of three (It has
overridden the copy-constructor, copy-assignment operator and the destructor to be able to copy the member variable `someBigAmountOfData`
correctly when copying the class and to be able to free the class without causing memory leaks).

The `DataManager` class has two member variables of type `HeavyData`. (See Below)

```
class HeavyData
{
public:
    HeavyData();

    HeavyData(const HeavyData& that);
    HeavyData& operator=(const HeavyData& that);
    ~HeavyData();

private:
    void* someBigAmountOfData; //maybe a few hundred bytes (on the heap, of course)
    size_t sizeOfData;
};


class DataManager
{
public:
    DataManager();

    //method 1
    DataManager(HeavyData one, HeavyData two):
        one(one),
        two(two)
    {
    }

    //method 2 (which I think is more effective than method 1)
    DataManager(const HeavyData& one, const HeavyData& two):
        one(one),
        two(two)
    {
    }

private:
    HeavyData one;
    HeavyData two;
};
```

**THE PROBLEM :**

The `DataManager` class has two constructors as follows:

1. `DataManager(HeavyData one, HeavyData two);` *//method 1*
2. `DataManager(const HeavyData& one, const HeavyData& two);` *//method 2*

The problem is in choosing a constructor from the above two. Which one do you think is more efficient ? And Why ?

*In think that the 2nd constructor (method 2) is more efficient.*

Comment: Perhaps a sprinkling of `std::cout` debug outputs to confirm/deny your suspicions.

Comment: Why do you think the second is more efficient?

Comment: Use a std::vector in `HeavyData` and follow the rule of zero. It will add move semantics to `HeavyData` so you can move arguments into `DataManager`

Comment: @RetiredNinja In the first method `one` and `two` are copied twice. First when they are passed to the constructor and then in the member initializer-list.

Answer (score 0):

passing by const reference will avoid an extra copy as stack values.  however, assignment of member variable during construction also copies.  maybe better: use a shared_ptr to allocate your HeavyData, and pass that around (never copy it to begin with!).  of course, it depends on how Heavy we're talking.

standard advice applies, of course: try both, and step through the copying.  measure the performance yourself, too!

Answer (score 0):

Using pointer and passing the argument by reference is always better then the passing the value.
This way you will able to use the many feature of `run time polymorphism` and it also avoiding the creating the extra `HeavyData` variable.